# Vscode Eslint for pure Javascript file

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

When using VsCode and working with React, Eslint can help me check the syntax. But when I code a pure JavaScript file, it does not work. How can I use the lint for pure Js in VsCode?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the VS Code Marketplace Symbol and search there for linters.

Then click on install it.

Comment: Eslint is a linter as well. I wonder why it does not work for pure js files.

Comment: Maybe you have to condigure the linter file

Comment: For a project with Node, Eslint automatically runs, and I can add `.eslintrc` if necessary.
But for a pure js file, I tried in vain.